# A Generic Generate SVG for IE9

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to add vertical split background to a Textarea in ie9. Unfortunately IE9 does not support CSS3 vertical split. I found a beautiful tool to generate cross browser css3 code to support all browsers at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. And it was written using prototypeJS

I just wanted to know if anyone has already written a pure SVG background generator function taking colors and % as the input..  Please help me on this. I am looking for function because I don't know much about SVG and it takes very long time.

Comment: As The ColorZilla gradient generator produces IE9 SVG gradients: What is it you want to know? And what is a **CSS3 vertical split**?

Comment: It will generate SVG background and that is what I wanted. But I am looking for a independent function for IE which can generate SVG code at client side whenever needed. Because all the elements backG color could not be static

Comment: I don't know of any – but you could check the code of the gradient generator.

Comment: SVG Gradients adapt to the size of the textarea if you use the right syntax, check out http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html